# Is there a shorter way of appending to a vector in a method call that takes self by value?

Tags: vector, methods, rust, traits

I need to append `Bar` to `Foo` as vectors. This solution works for me:

```
trait AppendBar {
    fn append_bar(self) -> Self;
}

impl AppendBar for Vec<String> {
    fn append_bar(self) -> Vec<String> {
        let mut v = self;
        v.push("Bar".to_string());
        v
    }
}

fn main(){
    let foo = vec![String::from("Foo")].append_bar();
    println!("{:#?}", foo)
    
}
```

Can I do something like this:

```
impl AppendBar for Vec<String> {
    fn append_bar(self) -> Vec<String> {
        let mut v = self.push("Bar".to_string());
        v
    }
}
```

Or this:

```
impl AppendBar for Vec<String> {
    fn append_bar(self) -> Vec<String> {
        self.push("Bar".to_string())
    }
}
```

Since I could not get it to compile with either of the last 2 attempts, I assume this is just how the language is, but I want to make sure I am not missing something to make it more simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to rebind `self` to `v` to achieve mutability. Just declare it as `mut self`:

```
fn append_bar(mut self) -> Vec<String> {
    self.push("Bar".to_string());
    self
}
```

Beyond that, there are no standard `Vec` methods for chaining modifications (consuming `self` and returning modified version), pretty much all methods modify the `Vec` in-place as `&mut self`.

Comment: Thank you @kmdreko, seeing this answer makes it much more clear. I was not sure if mut self could be used in the function signature as it was not declared in the trait. Much appreciated.

Comment: I've never dug into why `String` implements `+` but `Vec` doesn't. If it did, this could be a one-liner.